# PHP how to read EMAIL from php://input?

Tags: php, pipe, stdout, stdin

Using pipe.php which Converts piped emails to ticket by Peter Rotich (osTicket).
As it says: /* Read the message from STDIN */. The email is being forwarded to this script by an email forwarder in Virtualmin so standard stuff here guys & gals.

I want to intercept this STDIN and read the email before it continues with the normal process.

I have tried:

```
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = ""; // This will be the variable holding the data.
while (!feof($fd)) {
$email .= fread($fd, 10024);
}
fclose($fd);
```

This works and I can read the email, however, this destroys the input and cannot be read further down by the normal process which is:

```
require_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'api.tickets.php');
PipeApiController::process();
```

I do not want to dig into the PipeApiController. I want to just intercept the email and read something. Unfortunately there is no easy way to ask the PipeApiController for the email content either.

So I am guessing I have to read the email and pipe it back as I found it.
This is the full script:

```
/* Read STDIN into variable */
// $fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r"); //This creates problems 
$fd = fopen("php://input", "r"); //THIS IS OK
$email = ""; // This will be the variable holding the data.
while (!feof($fd)) {
$email .= fread($fd, 10024);
}
fclose($fd);

/* Saves the data into a file */
$fdw = fopen("/home/myhome/public_html/support/api/pipemail.txt", "w+");
fwrite($fdw, $email);
fclose($fdw);

/* Pass on the email for processing */
// $fdw = fopen("php://stdin", "w"); //This creates problems
$fdw = fopen("php://input", "w"); //THIS IS OK
fwrite($fdw, $email);
require_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'api.tickets.php');
PipeApiController::process();
fclose($fdw);
```

I was getting email parsing errors from the PipeApiController when reading and writing to php://stdin, so I changed it to php://input and it works OK! But now my pipemail.txt is BLANK!

**So my question now is:**

1. I can RELAY OK the contents of php://input to PipeApiController.
2. The problem now is that I cannot read what is inside php://input since I
   changed it from php://stdin in order to relay it.

**[update:]** I think in this case an email parser for the MIME type is needed. Maybe a different approach is needed to achieve this. I will update as soon as I find a solution.

Any ideas?

PS. This question has changed slightly since it first was posted, so I am changing the name to match and now maybe there is an easy answer for it. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP don't use fclose() if you need use the temporaly file later, because this function delete the temporaly's files. In other words omit the line:

fclose($fd);

Comment: It makes no difference in this case because the PipeApiController is not using my handle to read STDIN. Anyway I tried it and makes no difference. I can see that the problem is with encryption. I can write to STDIN without a problem.